# REACT JS, display the result of an sql "count" request in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, how do I display the value of a sql "COUNT" request in react? only with the get request that I displayed.

Here my code

**clientModel.js**

```
Client.getcount = function (result) {
connection.query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count_client FROM client",function(err,res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error: ", err);
        result(null, err);
    } else {
        result(null, res[0].count_client); 
    }
})
}
```

**clientController.js**

```
exports.getcount = function (req,res) {
Client.getcount(function(err, client) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    console.log('res_client', client);
    res.json({total_client: client});
});
}
```

code react
**client.jsx**

```
const getCountClients = () => {
axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/v1/clients/count-client")
.then((res) => { 
  setClients();
  console.log(res.data);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
  })  
};

useEffect(() => {
 getCountClients();
},[]);

<div className="featuredItem">
    <span className="featuredTitle">Effectifs totals</span>
    <div className="featuredNumberContainer">
      <span className="featuredNumber">2</span> //I want to 
        display it in place of "2"
      <span className="featuredNameInfo">Clients</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to display the value of "total_client" in a  tag in react. Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not complete, so I don't know what `setClients` does and where do you save your `total_client`. But I think this is how it should go:

**client.jsx**

```
const [totalClient, setTotalClient] = useState();

const getCountClients = () => {
  axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/v1/clients/count-client")
  .then((res) => { 
    setTotalClient(res.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
     console.log(error);
  })  
};

useEffect(() => {
 getCountClients();
},[]);

<div className="featuredItem">
    <span className="featuredTitle">Effectifs totals</span>
    <div className="featuredNumberContainer">
      <span className="featuredNumber">{totalClient}</span>
      <span className="featuredNameInfo">Clients</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, it worked, just specify the total_client key like this: {totalClient.total_client}